# Callback or event undefined in gulp 4 watch task when using gulp.series

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Inside my gulpfile I have the following task, where I would like to log the changed file's name:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    var stylesWatcher = gulp.watch(resolvePath(paths().source.scss) + '/**/*.scss', { awaitWriteFinish: true });

    stylesWatcher.on('change', gulp.series('styles', function(cb) {
        // Log filename here
        cb();
    }));

});
```

Keep in mind that `'styles'` is a gulp task.

I have tried to log it in multiple ways, i.e. using `function(path, stats)` instead of `function(cb)`, like it's shown in [the gulp 4 documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#fn-1).

An example of a result I get when I console.log the path while using the path and stats parameters like in the docs is:

```
function done() {
    d.removeListener('error', onError);
    d.exit();
    return cb.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

When I remove the 'styles' and the gulp.series though and just leave a function like this:

```
stylesWatcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
    console.log(path);
});
```

The path is indeed logged in the console.

Is there any way to console log the path when using gulp.series?